# Should an article title be capitalized if the word stylization disagrees?

Tags: titles, convention

I have students who have turned in their undergraduate thesis with a citation for a website:
http://www.foraker.com/ios-app-distribution-options/

The title of this article would be: 
"IOS App Distribution Options"

However iOS is always stylized as "iOS", thus "iOS App Distribution Options"

Given that the the way that titles are normally written disagrees with the way the pronoun is typically stylized which convention takes precedence?

P.S. I apologize for the question title, if someone has a better way to phrase it I will happily change it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Guardian style guide guys don't mention the capitalisation of *iOS* specifically at the beginning of sentences, however they [have stated](https://twitter.com/guardianstyle/status/192960864549220352) that when the word *iPad* appears at the start of a sentence, it should be capitalised as *Ipad*. However, *Ios* would look strange, and most people (myself included) would probably interpret *IOS* as a typo.

The [Trademarks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Manual_of_Style/Trademarks) section of Wikipedia's Manual of Style recommends *iOS*, but also states that you should try to avoid placing it at the beginning of a sentence.

However, as this is regarding a citation title I don't really think they're *actually* relevant. I was always taught to cite my sources accurately and not correct errors in the source text where they exist beyond inserting [sic] if necessary, so as the `<title>` and `<h1>` tags on the page you linked to are set to `<title>iOS App Distribution Options</title>` and `<h1>iOS App Distribution Options</h1>` respectively, I would use that capitalisation—*iOS App Distribution Options*—in my citation.

Incidentally, the block capitalisation of the main header on that site is merely a stylesheet effect which has been applied by the site's designers to the main heading for the page and is not indicative of the capitalisation of the actual text content contained within them.